Does the type-parameter in a multipart/related Accept-header need to be escaped?
I need to serve requests with headers
Accept: application/dicom+json

and/or
Accept: multipart/related; type="application/dicom+xml"

(dictated by Dicom QIDO-RS, for the curious ;))
While testing my implementation, I noticed that I do not need to escape the JSON header, but that I do need to escape the value of the type parameter in the XML header, in order to persuade our REST-framework to pass the correct string to my application code.
Digging deeper, I found RFC 2387, which states "If msg-id contains quoted-strings, those quote marks must be escaped.". That seems to apply to values of other types, like "start". The following sentence reads "Similarly, the type parameter contains the special character "/"." This applies to the type parameter, alright, but what I actually need to escape are the plus sign and the quotes. The document does not mention escaping in any other part.
So, what I want to know is, whether the type value does in fact need to be escaped, and if so, where is this defined?
